Retain size of error images when images have failed to load using an image loader
I am using KamelImage to load images to a LazyRow. However, when the images have failed to load I will show an error image. However, the problem is this error image never the same height as the success images.
Is there anyway to make them uniform so the height is the same for all images.
LazyRow
LazyRow(
    state = rememberLazyListState(),
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(horizontal = 8.dp),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
) {
    items(
        items = credits.cast.take(9),
        key = { cast ->
            cast.id
        }
    ) { cast ->
        CastItem(
            cast = cast
        ) {
            println("ID is $it")
        }
    }

    item {
        TextButton(
            onClick = {}
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "View More ->", fontSize = 18.sp, color = Color.Black,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
        }
    }
}

These are the items in the LazyRow
fun CastItem(
    cast: Cast,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onCastClicked: (id: Int) -> Unit
) {

        Card(
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .clickable {
                    onCastClicked(cast.id)
                },
            elevation = 2.dp
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 4.dp, bottom = 10.dp, start = 6.dp, end = 6.dp),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
            ) {
                KamelImage(
                    resource = { asyncPainterResource(data = cast.profilePath) },
                    contentDescription = cast.name,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .aspectRatio(16f/9f)
                        .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                    onLoading = { _ ->
                        CircularProgressIndicator(
                            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
                            color = Color.Blue
                        )
                    },
                    onFailure = {
                        Image(
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                            painter = painterResource(Res.drawable.person),
                            contentDescription = "Fall back image"
                        )
                        it.printStackTrace()
                    },
                )
    
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(6.dp))
    
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                    text = cast.name,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    fontSize = 14.sp
                )
    
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                    text = cast.character,
                    fontSize = 14.sp
                )
            }
        }
    }



I'm not sure but did you tried to set contentScale of the Image inside your onFailure() to ContentScale.Crop?

@NguyenTienDung I have tried setting to the ContentScale.Crop but that didn't work. Any ideas?

Your onFailure Image has fillMaxWidth modifier that should be replaced with fillMaxSize so it can fit with the other images. You might also set contentScale to ContentScale.Crop or ContentScale.FillBounds to fill Card's width.
Edit:
I tried the new code with person drawable of size 120x165 and following modifications: LazyRow modifier .height(300.dp) and .aspectRatio of (9f/16f) instead of (16f/9f) (so it looks more like the screenshot in question).
With
onFailure = {
    Image(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),


With
onFailure = {
    Image(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),


Screenshots were made on Compose desktop app.
Edit2:
Versions:
[versions]
androidx-lifecycle = "2.8.3"
compose-multiplatform = "1.7.0"
kotlin = "2.0.21"

Screen:
private data class Cast(val id: Int, val name: String, val character: String, val profilePath: String)

private val cast = listOf(
    Cast(1, "Teri Garr", "Sandy Lester", "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMmQ1MTdmNzAtZDI2ZS00NTNiLWI4NmItYzhhNzY4ZTA4ZDRmXkEyXkFqcGc@._V1_.jpg"),
    Cast(2, "Bob", "person", "notaurl"),
    Cast(3, "Kelsey Asbille", "Monica Dutton", "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNzIzYmQzZTMtYTQ3Yy00NmNjLThiMzgtMzIzMWY3MzhkMjg2XkEyXkFqcGc@._V1_.jpg"),
)

@Composable
fun ErrorImageSize() {
    LazyRow(
        state = rememberLazyListState(),
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
            .height(300.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        items(
//            items = credits.cast.take(9),
            items = cast,
            key = { cast ->
                cast.id
            }
        ) { cast ->
            CastItem(
                cast = cast
            ) {
                println("ID is $it")
            }
        }
        item {
            TextButton(
                onClick = {}
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "View More ->", fontSize = 18.sp, color = Color.Black,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun CastItem(
    cast: Cast,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onCastClicked: (id: Int) -> Unit
) {
    Card(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .clickable {
                onCastClicked(cast.id)
            },
        elevation = 2.dp
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 4.dp, bottom = 10.dp, start = 6.dp, end = 6.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
        ) {
            KamelImage(
                resource = { asyncPainterResource(data = cast.profilePath) },
                contentDescription = cast.name,
                modifier = Modifier
//                    .aspectRatio(16f/9f)
                    .aspectRatio(9f / 16f)
                    .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                onLoading = { _ ->
                    CircularProgressIndicator(
                        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
                        color = Color.Blue
                    )
                },
                onFailure = {
                    Image(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                        painter = painterResource(Res.drawable.person),
                        contentDescription = "Fall back image"
                    )
                    it.printStackTrace()
                },
            )

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(6.dp))

            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                text = cast.name,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                fontSize = 14.sp
            )

            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                text = cast.character,
                fontSize = 14.sp
            )
        }
    }
}


I have tried setting to the ContentScale.Crop and ContentScale.FillBounds but neither didn't work. I also changed to fillMaxSize(). That didn't work either. I have updated the question with your suggestions. Any other ideas?

What kind of layout these cards are in? I've tried putting them in a Row and images looked fine, but text below was gone, so it looked very different from your screenshot. @ant2009

Also, on your screenshot the middle card itself looks smaller, even if it has fillMaxHeight modifier, so its height shouln't be affected by onFailure composable. @ant2009

I have updated my question with the entire code that these cards are in. So basically they are in the a LazyRow. I was thinking the problem would be the card. Thank you :)

I can't reproduce the issue. I've added screenshots of what it looks like for me. @ant2009

Hi JanItor is it possible for you to share the gist of your code so I can compare it with mine?

I've added more code. @ant2009

Your code does not set a fixed height-constraint to the LazyRow like the code @Jan Itor does.
Your LazyRow-modifier:
modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(horizontal = 8.dp)

Jan Itors LazyRow-modifier:
modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
        .height(300.dp)

Since your LazyRow does not constraint the maximum height, fillMaxHeight and, in deduction fillMaxSize do not equalize both types of images since they don't have a height-max to fill against.

The problem maybe the Column in the Card. You can try to add .fillMaxHeight() to Column's modifier.
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 4.dp, bottom = 10.dp, start = 6.dp, end = 6.dp).fillMaxHeight(),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
)

Note that this line:
Image(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), etc.)

may cause the error, because you are trying to set the maximum width (because the size is both the height and the width) to a element (Lazy Row) that has infinite width.
So the .fillMaxSize() function may not work.
